# How can I sort the characters of a string in Rust?

Tags: string, sorting, rust

I have the string "laxmi" and I need to sort it in descending alphabetical order, producing "xmlia". I have written this:

```
fn main() {
    let wordy: String = "I am a hello world example";

    let chars: Vec<char> = wordy.chars().vector();
    chars.sort_by(|a, b| b.cmp(a));

    // let s: String = chars.into_iter().collect();
    println!("test{:?}", chars);
    let s = String::from_iter(chars);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

This only works if `wordy` is a `&str`, but I have a `String`. How can I convert the `String` to a vector of `char` so that I can sort the string?

Comment: This is not even valid code, so I don't see how you can say "this only works...". It produces multiple errors: *mismatched types*;  *no method named `vector` found for type `std::str::Chars<'_>`*; *no associated item named `from_iter` found for type `std::string::String`*. Please review how to create a [MCVE] when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 16):

I did this and got the desired output. However this may not be the best way.

```
use std::iter::Iterator;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    let wordy: String = "I am a hello world example".to_owned();
    let s_slice: &str = &wordy[..];

    let mut chars: Vec<char> = s_slice.chars().collect();
    chars.sort_by(|a, b| b.cmp(a));

    println!("test{:?}", chars);
    let s = String::from_iter(chars);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't know how you got this error. however I am getting the correct output without error. the overall program with headers are edited in the answer. and I am able to compile the program without errors. You may have missed the use std::iter::FromIterator; header.

Comment: I got the error by copying your code and running it. Since you did not include the entire valid example, it had an error. If you **don't provide the  code, how would anyone else looking at the answer know what to use**?

Comment: Note, that you can use `chars.into_iter().collect::<String>()` instead of `String::from_iter` (from `FromIterator`).

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay with using crates, you can use the `itertools` crate to simplify things quite a bit.

Add the crate to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
itertools = "0.9.0"
```

Then use it in your file to sort and reverse the string.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let wordy = "I am a hello world example";

    let s = wordy.chars().sorted().rev().collect::<String>();

    println!("{}", s);
}
```